# Converting Date format in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my table for storing dates and it is in `12-06-2013 15:32:45`. I want to convert it to `MM/DD/YYYY` format. How can I do it?

Coulmn type is varchar

Comment: It's unclear. Is your current format `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Comment: http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: What is the data type of your column which stores that date? Did you do any research or internet search related to your problem? What did you try so far? What was wrong with the solutions you tried?

Answer (score 1):

First  you need to `CONVERT` `VARCHAR()` to `datetime` type and and then to `CONVERT` it to **string** in desired format:

```
SELECT  CONVERT (varchar (10), CONVERT (date,'12-06-2013 15:32:45' ,103),101)
```

First `103` is used to interpret current date format, and second - `101` - target format.

If you change target date format from `varchar` to `date` then your output in MSMS will be in default display date format of you SQL Server, not the desired format. This is because SQL Server stores dates as integers and converts them before dispalying the value. Therefore if you need to store in certain format, then store in `VARCHAR` type.

Check out [CAST and CONVERT functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) on MDSN

Answer (score 0):

or you can do it in your c# code like that :

First you have to take your date from your table and put it in string var "DT" exemple :

```
 string strDT =db.TableTitle.date;

 string date = strDT .ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");
 DateTime DT = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

then you can use the DT time variable :)